# d3 separating click and drag from nodes and background

Tags: graph, d3.js

I'm trying to enable dragging behavior in a d3 force graph so that it's possible to click on the background (not nodes or links) and drag (pan) the whole graph but also independently click and drag a node (without panning the entire graph). While I can get each to work separately, when I combine the code, the background rect seems to over-ride the nodes so that I can no longer drag a node without dragging the whole graph. I've included the two relevant pieces of code below and would really appreciate any help!

This code lets me pan and zoom the entire graph:

```
vis = d3.select("#chart")
.append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .append("svg:g")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
    .append("svg:g");
```

This code lets me drag and click on a node - but only when the above code is not included:

```
      var node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
      .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", 6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return groupColors[(d.group)-1]; }) // fill(d.group)
      .on("click", function(d) {
            node.style("stroke","#FFFFFF");
            d3.select(this).style("stroke","red");
            clickNode(d);
            })
      .call(force.drag);
```

Comment: Well, the answer appears to be upgrading to the current version (d3.v2). After I did this, the independent dragging that I was after works! I'd answer my own question but I have to wait 8 hours...

Comment: I assume your redraw = function() {
 vis.attr("transform","translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"); } 
?

Comment: i have implemented the graph the same as you but my force directed graph is undraggable. can you please publish your entire code for this feature?